# End date does not change when start date is changed in javascript using datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to work on a start date and end date in javascript using datepicker. I have jQuery 2.1.1. I cannot change the jQuery version because there are other methods that are using this version in the application. The setStartDate, setEndDate and setDate are not changing by clicking or changing the date manually. Any suggestion, tips or help will be greatly appreciated. Here is my code below:

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var currentDate = new Date();
                $('.hasStartDate').datepicker({
                    autoClose: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    minDate: '-1m',
                    maxDate: '+3m',
                    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
                }).on('changeDate', function(e){
                    $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', e.date),
                    $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', e.date + 364),
                    $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('setStartDate', e.date),
                    $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('setEndDate', e.date + 364),
                    $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('setDate', e.date + 364),
                    $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('refresh')
                });
                $('.hasStartDate').datepicker('setDate', currentDate);

                var tdate = $('.hasStarDate').datepicker('getDate');
                var ddate = tdate + 364;
                $('.hasEndDate').datepicker({
                    autoClose: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    minDate: tdate + 1,
                    maxDate: ddate,
                    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
                }).on('changeDate', function(e){
                    $('.hasStartDate').datepicker('setEndDate', e.date)
                });
                $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('setDate', ddate);
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: To add info, the script is on a separate js file and is used as CSS in asp.net textbox. I removed the updatepanel because after selecting a date, the date picker window no longer displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. On selecting a date, split it into day, month, year and construct min and max dates and [set it using `options` dynamically](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hasStartDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        autoClose: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '-1m',
        maxDate: '+3m',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect:function(date){
            var d = date.split("/");
            d = d.map(function(item){return parseInt(item)});
            var mindate = new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2]+1);
            var maxdate = new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2]+365);
            $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('option','minDate',mindate);
            $('.hasEndDate').datepicker('option','maxDate', maxdate);
        }
    });
    
    $('.hasEndDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        autoClose: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="hasStartDate"/>
<input class="hasEndDate"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Vignesh. Can you make the display mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Or it will not work unless you use "yy/mm/dd" as dateFormat?